# Re-structuring a pandas DataFrame per row and column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
tuples = [
    ['00:00:00','','','00:00:15','','','00:00:30','',''],
    ['37.0','','','37.1','','','36.9','','']
    ]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(tuples, names=['time', 'temp'])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12'],
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12'],
        ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12'],

        ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12'],
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12'],
        ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12'],

        ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12'],
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12'],
        ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12']
        ],
        index=index,
        columns=(range(12))
        )
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11
time     temp                                                   
00:00:00 37.0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
               B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10  B11  B12
               C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
00:00:15 37.1  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
               B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10  B11  B12
               C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
00:00:30 36.9  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
               B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10  B11  B12
               C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
```

The values A1, A2, are actually numbers but for simplicity I printed these coordinates. However, what I want is this:

```
time     temp
00:00:00 37.0  A1  A2  ...  C10  C11  C12
00:00:15 37.1  A1  A2  ...  C10  C11  C12
00:00:30 36.9  A1  A2  ...  C10  C11  C12
```

To be honest, I don't even have a clue what I should look for in the pandas documentation.

By stupidly iterating over the rows, I managed to get it right for the respective first row:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df2[col] = [df.loc[i, col] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 8)]
```

I also tried adding helper columns and then df.groupby(), but that I didn't know what to do with it:

```
rows = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lines = int(df.shape[0])
blocks = int(lines / len(rows))

df['line'] = (rows * (blocks + 1))[:lines]
df['block'] = [i for i in range(3) for block in range(blocks)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reliably have 3 measurements per temperature/time, then you can use NumPy as your data is full-dimensional (meaning ALL outerlevels of your MultiIndex have the same number of sublevels.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=df.to_numpy().reshape(3, -1),
    index=df.index[df.index != ('' ,'')]
)

print(df)
#                0   1   2   3   4   ...  31  32   33   34   35
# time     temp                      ...
# 00:00:00 37.0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# 00:00:15 37.1  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# 00:00:30 36.9  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# [3 rows x 36 columns]
```

If you cannot make the above assumptions about the dimensionality of the data (e.g. time/temperature each having 3 sublevels) then you can use some `pandas` reshaping mechanisms:

```py
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(index.to_frame().replace('', np.nan).ffill())
new_df = (
    df.set_axis(new_index) # 1. Fix the irregular MultiIndex
    .pipe(lambda d:        # 2. Calculate group boundaries 
        d.set_index(d.groupby('time').cumcount(), append=True)
    )
    .unstack()             # 3. Reshape data according to calculated boundaries
    .swaplevel(axis=1)     # 4. Resort the columns for expected ordering
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)

print(new_df)
#                0                   ...  2
#                0   1   2   3   4   ...  7   8    9    10   11
# time     temp                      ...
# 00:00:00 37.0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# 00:00:15 37.1  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# 00:00:30 36.9  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# [3 rows x 36 columns]

# ---
# Note the MultiIndex on the columns here, we can remove it with the following:

print(
    new_df.set_axis(pd.RangeIndex(0, stop=len(new_df.columns)), axis=1)
)
#                0   1   2   3   4   ...  31  32   33   34   35
# time     temp                      ...
# 00:00:00 37.0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# 00:00:15 37.1  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# 00:00:30 36.9  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  ...  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
# [3 rows x 36 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Since I have reliably the same number of measurements per time point, I could count the number of measurements by simply doing

```
timepoints = df['time'].dropna()
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(len(timepoints), -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the other answer is right, I thought splitting the original df into three might be helpful for you. The easiest way being:

```
import numpy as np
df_list = np.array_split(df, 3)
```

or create your own function taking the df and number to group by:

```
def split_dataframe(df, grp_by=3):
    return [df[i:i + grp_by].copy()
            for i in range(0, df.shape[0], grp_by)]
```

both will give you the following (a list of dfs after grouping by 3:

```
[
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11
time     temp                                                   
00:00:00 37.0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
               B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10  B11  B12
               C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12,                
               
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11
time     temp                                                   
00:00:15 37.1  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
               B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10  B11  B12
               C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12,                
               
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11
time     temp                                                   
00:00:30 36.9  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
               B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10  B11  B12
               C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  C12
]
```

Comment: Indeed I also tried splitting the DataFrame into a list, but since its a continuous data set, directly reshaping it will work in most/all cases.